# CSS problem with x-scroll bar

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
#exposoures ul{padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="exposoures" style="width: 100px;height:50px; overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;  background-color: #ccc;">
    <ul>
        <li>row 1 col 1</li>
        <li>row 2 col 1</li>
        <li>row 3 col 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>row 1 col 1</li>
        <li>row 2 col 1</li>
        <li>row 3 col 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>row 1 col 1</li>
        <li>row 2 col 1</li>
        <li>row 3 col 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>row 1 col 1</li>
        <li>row 2 col 1</li>
        <li>row 3 col 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here I have above div containing multiple uls now problem with `overflow-x:scroll`. I wasn't able to get scroll bar for `x-axis`.. could any one help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Judging by the above code, surely you are looking for the y-overflow to scroll, not the (non-existant) x-overflow? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the words are wrapped, so when it reach the width limit it just flows to the next line, which is hidden due to the `overflow-y: hidden` rule.

To avoid the wrapping add `white-space:nowrap;` to the DIV:

```
#exposoures { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/PqR5x/1/